# jquery countdown variable not parsed

Tags: jquery, variables, countdown

so the variable isn't being parsed properly and I can't understand why. I'm using the jquery countdown plugin. Here's the code

```
var dateCD = '2013, 11 - 1, 01, 08';

function countdownLeft() {
$('.countdownLeft').countdown({ 
layout:'<div class="countdownBlock cdFirst"><div class="cdTop">Race</div><div class="cdBottom">01</div> </div><div class="countdownBlock"><div class="cdTop">{dl}</div><div class="cdBottom">{dnn}</div> </div>  <div class="countdownBlock"><div class="cdTop">{hl}</div><div class="cdBottom">{hnn}</div> </div><div class="countdownBlock"><div class="cdTop">{ml}</div><div class="cdBottom">{mnn}</div> </div> <div class="countdownBlock cdLast"><div class="cdTop">{sl}</div><div class="cdBottom">{snn}</div> </div>',
     until: new Date(dateCD)});
};
```

and the output I get shows exactly the same as above so the variable isn't being picked up. It's not a scope issue and just to double check I logged the correct variable result from inside the function.

Any ideas?

Comment: i think you need to construct dateCD using `new Date();`

Comment: I already tried this  until: new Date(dateCD)}); and that didn't work either: going to update the main post to reflect this

Comment: hey Asad, date format aside - why is the variable not being called correctly? surely it should still pull in the date rather than just displaying the variable name?

Answer (score 0):

`new Date()` doesn't work like that - given you're using "month - 1" it looks like you've read the docs and misunderstood them.

When using "month - 1" you're *supposed* to supply those fields as *separate* numeric parameters, which also happens to be the most reliable way of using `new Date()`:

```
until: new Date(2013, 11 - 1, 1, 8)
```

If your input is really a string you're better off parsing that into its component fields manually and then calling `new Date()` with the required parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your date format doesn't seem parsable. Try using the following formats:

```
new Date();
new Date(value);
new Date(dateString);
new Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond]);
```

Check out the link below for more about Date function

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Also it would help to specify which plugin you are using. Try attaching a link to where you got the plugin.

Good luck.